# mariadb-server error table doesn't exist in engine status : Operation failed

Tags: database, failed

I tried import a db template into the server and during the process the server has got corrupted. All kind of error come up.
Anyway the most crucial step is get it back to work.

```
...
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
...
...
Error    : Table 'mysql.transaction_registry' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
...
...
Phase 4/7: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
ERROR 1813 (HY000) at line 153: Tablespace for table '`mysql`.`gtid_slave_pos`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT
ERROR 1932 (42S02) at line 639: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist in engine
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 640: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1932 (42S02) at line 642: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist in engine
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 643: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1932 (42S02) at line 647: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist in engine
ERROR 1932 (42S02) at line 651: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist in engine
ERROR 1932 (42S02) at line 654: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist in engine
```

Environment: 10.3.27-MariaDB
Remove didn't work.
I am considering purge option, but I am afraid of deleting some crucial files.

Comment: Most reliable way to get system in good state is to re-install MariaDB and restore database from backups.